# Is it possible to doa layer 2 Packet Capture in Powershell

Tags: powershell, networking, capture, ethernet

Is it possible to capture Layer 2 traffic using powershell? I've seen methods that use sockets, but they only seem to capture traffic on Layer 3 and higher. I want to look at Ethernet frames; but I'm not sure if it can be done in powershell. Is it possible to do this without installing any extra software/drivers on a system (maybe using a dll or something)?

Comment: Have you looked in to just using Wire Shark or interfacing with its underlying library WinPcap?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain WireShark gets the information I want, but I'm looking for a portable solution that can be scripted.

Comment: I think the problem you are going to run in to is the default drivers built in to windows don't expose the information you are looking for, WinPcap adds that information back in. You must "install" the WinPcap driver, but [you could make that install silent](http://paperlined.org/apps/wireshark/winpcap_silent_install.html) and you could have your program uninstall when done. I don't think you will be able to get access to layer 2 information without doing a driver install.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain That's what I was afraid of. I was hoping for some type of "portable winpcap" that could expose the information without an install.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need portable without being silent you could use the [portable Wireshark](http://wiki.wireshark.org/WiresharkPortable) to "temporarily install" the needed drivers then use Wireshark's [command line switches](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCustCommandLine.html) to script it with powershell.

One other option is if WinPcap is already installed (you could script the install and uninstall in your powershell file) you could use a wrapper library like [Pcap.Net](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/) which would allow you to communicate directly to the driver via your script without going through Wireshark.